# Repopulate a table of results with results that match a search

Tags: php, mysql, search, html-table, echo

I have the following code which echoes out pupil info from a database automatically. However when the user searches for a specific pupil I need to repopulate the same table with relevant pupils to the search request.

All help is greatly appreciated!

```
if(!isset ($_POST['search'])){
$pupils = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pupil") or die("Cant find Pupils");
$count = mysql_num_rows($pupils);    
if ($count == 0 ) {
    $totalpupil = "There are currently no Pupils in the system.";     
} else{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($pupils)){
        ?>                                        
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo '<a href="profile.php?    id='.$row['pupil_id'].'">'.$row['pupil_id'].'</a>'; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['pupil_name']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['class_id']?></td>
                    <td><a href="pupiledit.php?id='.$id.'">Edit</a> | <a     href="pupildelete.php?id='.$id.'">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
    }       
}
}
```

Comment: why not just define `WHERE pupil_id = ?` to the query ? The result will populate the table the same way it did without the `WHERE`

Comment: because the current code displays all students automatically, which is what i want. However when a user searches i need to filter all pupils down to those that are similar to the search. is that better to understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
if(!isset ($_POST['search'])){
 $pupils = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pupil") or die("Cant find Pupils");
}
elseif(isset($_POST['search'])){

 $search_param = "%".$_POST['search']."%";
 $pupils = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pupil WHERE LOWER(pupil_name) LIKE LOWER($search_param)") or die("Cant find Pupils");
}

$count = mysql_num_rows($pupils);

if($count == 0){
 $totalpupil = "There are currently no Pupils in the system."; 
}
else{
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($pupils)){
    ?>                                        
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo '<a href="profile.php?    id='.$row['pupil_id'].'">'.$row['pupil_id'].'</a>'; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['pupil_name']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['class_id']?></td>
                <td><a href="pupiledit.php?id='.$id.'">Edit</a> | <a     href="pupildelete.php?id='.$id.'">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
}
```

I'm assuming that you are searching in the `pupil_name` column.